# Prestashop, cambio del simbolo de moneda

Tags: prestashop, prestashop1.7

Necesito realizar unos cambios en la moneda que utilizo en mi tienda Prestashop.

Algunos datos en consideracion:

1. La tienda solamente es en espanol.
2. La tienda utilizara como moneda principal el Lempira Hondureno (HNL)
3. Archivo que intento modificar es es.XML

**Lo que estoy buscando:**

Intento realizar 3 cambios sin exito, `Simbolo HNL por L` , `Punto por coma`, `Coma por punto`. Adjunto fotografia.

[image: Img1]

De esta forma quiero que mis productos muestren la informacion asi: `4,500.00 L`

**Lo que he intentado:**

Yendo al directorio `/localization/CLDR/core/common/main/es.XML`

Veo que son los siguientes bloques de codigos [originales]:

```
    <currency type="HNL">
        <displayName>lempira hondureño</displayName>
        <displayName count="one">lempira hondureño</displayName>
        <displayName count="other">lempiras hondureños</displayName>
        <symbol>HNL</symbol>
        <symbol alt="narrow" draft="contributed">HNL</symbol>
    </currency>
<currencyFormats numberSystem="latn">
    <currencyFormatLength>
        <currencyFormat type="standard">
            <pattern> #.##0,00 ¤</pattern>
        </currencyFormat>
        <currencyFormat type="accounting">
            <pattern> #.##0,00 ¤</pattern>
        </currencyFormat>
    </currencyFormatLength>
    <currencyFormatLength type="short">
        <currencyFormat type="standard">
            <pattern type="1000" count="one">0 mil ¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="1000" count="other">0 mil ¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="10000" count="one">00 mil ¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="10000" count="other">00 mil ¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="100000" count="one">000 mil ¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="100000" count="other">000 mil ¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="1000000" count="one">0 M¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="1000000" count="other">0 M¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="10000000" count="one">00 M¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="10000000" count="other">00 M¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="100000000" count="one">000 M¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="100000000" count="other">000 M¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="1000000000" count="one">0000 M¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="1000000000" count="other">0000 M¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="10000000000" count="one">00 mil M¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="10000000000" count="other">00 mil M¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="100000000000" count="one">000 mil M¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="100000000000" count="other">000 mil M¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="1000000000000" count="one">0 B¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="1000000000000" count="other">0 B¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="10000000000000" count="one">00 B¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="10000000000000" count="other">00 B¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="100000000000000" count="one">000 B¤</pattern>
            <pattern type="100000000000000" count="other">000 B¤</pattern>
        </currencyFormat>
    </currencyFormatLength>
    <unitPattern count="one">{0} {1}</unitPattern>
    <unitPattern count="other">{0} {1}</unitPattern>
</currencyFormats>
```

He modificado el documento por el siguiente codigo [modificado]:

```
<currencyFormats numberSystem="latn">
            <currencyFormatLength>
                <currencyFormat type="standard">
                    <pattern> #,##0.00 ¤</pattern>
                </currencyFormat>
                <currencyFormat type="accounting">
                    <pattern> #,##0.00 ¤</pattern>
                </currencyFormat>
            </currencyFormatLength>
            <currencyFormatLength type="short">
                <currencyFormat type="standard">
                    <pattern type="1000" count="one">¤ 0 mil </pattern>
                    <pattern type="1000" count="other">0 mil ¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="10000" count="one">00 mil ¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="10000" count="other">00 mil ¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="100000" count="one">000 mil ¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="100000" count="other">000 mil ¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="1000000" count="one">0 M¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="1000000" count="other">0 M¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="10000000" count="one">00 M¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="10000000" count="other">00 M¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="100000000" count="one">000 M¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="100000000" count="other">000 M¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="1000000000" count="one">0000 M¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="1000000000" count="other">0000 M¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="10000000000" count="one">00 mil M¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="10000000000" count="other">00 mil M¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="100000000000" count="one">000 mil M¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="100000000000" count="other">000 mil M¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="1000000000000" count="one">0 B¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="1000000000000" count="other">0 B¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="10000000000000" count="one">00 B¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="10000000000000" count="other">00 B¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="100000000000000" count="one">000 B¤</pattern>
                    <pattern type="100000000000000" count="other">000 B¤</pattern>
                </currencyFormat>
```

Despues de estos cambios he borrado el CACHE del navegador y el CACHE de mi tienda en mi Backoffice,
Pero sin embargo, ninguno de los cambios que realice tuvieron efectos.

Alguien puede darme una mano con esto?

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que no valga con modificar el archivo xml, también lo tendrás que insertar en base de datos. ¿Por qué no lo creas desde el propio gestor del prestashop? el mismo creará el xml y lo insertará en base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y después de rellenarlo podrá elegir el formato decimal que quiera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que le pueda servir de ayuda, un saludo

Comment: Hola @borchvm no se que version de prestashop estas usando pero en 1.7, lo especifico en las tags, no me aparece asi solamente te deja modificar 2 valores, 1 * moneda y * tasa de cambio.

Comment: yo uso la 1.6.1.10, pero es verdad que en la 1.7 quitaron esas opciones. Hay usuarios que aportan alguna otra solución el los foros de prestashop, aqui puedes ampliar más información si quieres:  https://victor-rodenas.com/gestionar-monedas-en-prestashop-1-7/

Comment: gracias por tu aporte, antes de hacer publica mi pregunta en SOes investigue por mi cuenta en los foros de Prestashop y lo que he intentado ha salido de esas investigaciones. Pero a mi no me han funcionado esas soluciones, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

yo uso prestashop 1.7 y para agregar el símbolo de la moneda lo hice desde de estos archivos:

C:\xampp\htdocs\modules\itleftnewproducts\views\templates\hook\itleftnewproducts.tpl(56)
C:\xampp\htdocs\modules\itleftspecialproducts\views\templates\hook\itleftspecialproducts.tpl(56)
C:\xampp\htdocs\modules\itproductfilter\views\templates\hook\product-column.tpl(67)
C:\xampp\htdocs\modules\itproductfilter\views\templates\hook\product.tpl(34)
C:\xampp\htdocs\themes\WT1043\templates\catalog_partials\miniatures\product.tpl(97)
C:\xampp\htdocs\themes\WT1043\templates\catalog_partials\miniatures\productGrid.tpl(99)
C:\xampp\htdocs\themes\WT1043\templates\catalog_partials\miniatures\productList.tpl(68)
C:\xampp\htdocs\themes\WT1043\templates\catalog_partials\miniatures\productSpecial.tpl(42)

cada archivo se refiere a una vista de la tienda, y el numero es una referencia de la línea, por ejemplo el primer archivo quedaría así, en la línea 57 se hace la modificación, yo tengo MXN pero en tu caso le pondrías L

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

después de hacer los cambios recuerda borrar cache de prestashop en la sección de performance :)

Comment: Hola @Ana gracias por tu aporte, Estaba viendo en mi bloque de product.tpl Y en la linea 57 <span itemprop="price"... si yo agrego la palabra L, me aparece 4.500,00 HNL L es decir que la variable $product.price te trae el HNL, sabes en que archivo .php esta esa variable? Saludos Cordiales.

Comment: ¿Que tema estás usando?

Comment: Hola @Ana estoy usando un tema de Zemez, llamado Nextprest electronics.